# Priority Queue in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am adding data in priority queue in the form of `(priority,data)` but when I use the function `get()`, I get back my priority instead of data. Also, if I add in the form of `(data,priority)`, it is sorted by data values.

here is my trial code

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue
q= PriorityQueue(0)
q.put(4,8)
q.put(3,7)
q.put(2,6)
q.put(1,5)
while not q.empty():
    item = q.get()[1]
    print item,
print

q= PriorityQueue(0)
q.put(4,5)
q.put(3,6)
q.put(2,7)
q.put(1,8)
while not q.empty():
    item = q.get()[1]
    print item,
print
```

first one is giving error 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable 
and second one 
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getitem'

Comment: Please add your code so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A priority queue works like a standard queue except that the items are tuples of `priority, item`, so `get()` on such a queue will return that kind of tuple - if you want to get the actual item you should use either this which will give you both the item and its priority :

```
prio, item = queue.get()
```

Or directly like this if you don't care about the priority at all :

```
item = queue.get()[1]
```

See the [official Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue) for more info.

Edit: your comment shows that you put the values in your queue with `put(4, 8)`, so you're only putting `4` and the `8` becomes the `block` argument of [`put()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.put) - **you need to put a tuple** like so :

```
queue.put((4, 8))
```

Comment: first one is giving error 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
and second one
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
here is my trial code

from Queue import PriorityQueue
q= PriorityQueue(0)
q.put(4,8)
q.put(3,7)
q.put(2,6)
q.put(1,5)
while not q.empty():
  item = q.get()[1]
  print item,
print

q= PriorityQueue(0)
q.put(4,5)
q.put(3,6)
q.put(2,7)
q.put(1,8)
while not q.empty():
  item = q.get()[1]
  print item,
print

Comment: @Ruturaj what error ? Edit your question and add your error and your code. Also are you sure that your queue is actually a `PriorityQueue` and not something else ?

Comment: Items are not necessarily tuples of the form (priority, data). Items may be any comparable object.